# multiple step form/ option value disappears from SESSION

Tags: php, html, forms

first page

```
 <?php session_start();?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>





    <form method="post" action="form.php">
    <select name="list1"> 

     <option value="NY"> ny</option>
     <option value="NJ"> nj</option>
     <option value="DE"> de</option>   
     </select>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>


    <h1><?php
    print_r($_SESSION);
    ?></h1>


    </body>
    </html>
```

second page

```
    <?php   session_start();?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html> 
    <body>


    <?php
    $_SESSION["list"] = $_POST["list1"];

    $list = $_SESSION['list'];

    ?>


   <form action="form1.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name1"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email1"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>


    <br>
    <h1>   chosen number <br />>>>  <?echo $list; ?>   </h1>

   <br>
   <h1><?php
    print_r($_SESSION);
    ?></h1>
```

after this comes third step, where selected state disappears from SESSION array,this is a multiple step form, there are 4 - 5 steps and starting from second page all they till form processing page all text entries get stored in the SESSION array

Comment: You've given us page 1 and page 2, which I assume are steps 1 and 2. Show us what you're using for steps 3-4-5. If `session_start();` isn't inside those, then you'll lose the session array.

Comment: session start is included in all pages

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything then.